# Updating the BIOS resulted in BSOD with 0x1c error code

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I was trying to update my BIOS, and when it asks to start the flashing process, it gives me a `0xc1` error.

My system configuration:

- DELL laptop
- Windows 7 64-bit
- 2 x 4 GB Ram
- Intel HD Graphics

Here is the WinDbg bugcheck result:

```
SPECIAL_POOL_DETECTED_MEMORY_CORRUPTION (c1)
Special pool has detected memory corruption.  Typically the current thread's
stack backtrace will reveal the guilty party.
Arguments:
Arg1: fffff9800324afe0, address trying to free
Arg2: fffff9800324aff4, address where bits are corrupted
Arg3: 00000000007d0014, (reserved)
Arg4: 0000000000000024, caller is freeing an address where bytes after the end of the allocation have been overwritten

Debugging Details:
------------------


BUGCHECK_STR:  0xC1_24

SPECIAL_POOL_CORRUPTION_TYPE:  24

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VERIFIER_ENABLED_VISTA_MINIDUMP

PROCESS_NAME:  N5010A15.EXE

CURRENT_IRQL:  1

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9431.0 (debuggers(dbg).130615-1214) amd64fre

IRP_ADDRESS:  fffff9801e85af3b

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80004bcfa94 to fffff80004ac7b80

STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
amifldrv64+1c7f
fffff880`08a72c7f ??              ???

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  6

SYMBOL_NAME:  amifldrv64+1c7f

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: amifldrv64

IMAGE_NAME:  amifldrv64.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  490faf89

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xC1_24_VRF_amifldrv64+1c7f

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xC1_24_VRF_amifldrv64+1c7f

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0xc1_24_vrf_amifldrv64+1c7f

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {8fed56d3-4f5e-b7ba-5656-8cc13c7dff12}

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

0: kd> lmvm amifldrv64
start             end                 module name
fffff880`08a71000 fffff880`08a78000   amifldrv64 T (no symbols)           
    Loaded symbol image file: amifldrv64.sys
    Image path: \??\C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\amifldrv64.sys
    Image name: amifldrv64.sys
    Timestamp:        Tue Nov 04 02:12:25 2008 (490FAF89)
    CheckSum:         000064B3
    ImageSize:        00007000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Disable Driver Verifier](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/101379-driver-verifier-enable-disable.html) before trying to flash the BIOS.

Comment: Thank you sir, may i ask, is enabling Driver Verifier all the time a good idea ?

Comment: no this is not a good idea. You should only activate it if you get a lot of bugchecks and the normal dumps don't tell you which driver caused the crash. Driver Verifier also effects performance so it is not a good idea to use it all the time.